# Forward rendering multiple rendering passes

Tags: opengl, glsl, rendering

I'm trying to implement PBR into my simple OpenGL renderer and trying to use multiple lighting passes, I'm using one pass per light for rendering as follow:

1- First pass = depth

2- Second pass = ambient

3- [3 .. n] for all the lights in the scene.

I'm using the blending function glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE) for passes [3..n], and i'm doing a Gamma Correction at the end of each fragment shader.

But i still have a problem with the output image it just looks noisy specially when i'm using texture maps.

Is there anything wrong with those steps or is there any improvement to this process?

Comment: "*i'm doing a Gamma Correction at the end of each fragment shader.*" You shouldn't be. Gamma correction transforms linear values into non-linear, gamma-space values. You shouldn't do blending in gamma space; blending should only be applied to linear values.

Comment: So @NicolBolas do you have any idea about to solve this? as if i didn't do the gamma correction the output image is very dark.

Comment: Do gamma correction once at the end, obviously. I don't see any reason for the result to be noisy. Could you share an example image? There is nothing stochastic in your renderer, right?

Comment: Some of the improvementsyou can do is combine depth prepass with ambient pass making it one pass. Next put materials in queues based on materials. So youhave opaque objects, objects casting shadows and objects transparent.then render each queue for all lights rendering transparent queue in last.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, what you're calculating is

```
f(x) = a^gamma + b^gamma + ...
```

However, what you actually want (and as noted by @NicolBolas in the comments already) is

```
g(x) = (a + b + ...)^gamma
```

Now `f(x)` and `g(x)` will only equal each other in the rather useless cases like `gamma=1`. You simply cannot additively decompose a nonlinear function like power that way.

The correct solution is to blend everything together in linear space, and doing the gamma correction afterwards, on the total sum of the linear contributions of each light source.

However, implementing this will lead to a couple of technical issues. First and foremost, the standard 8 bit per channel are just not precise enough to store *linear* color values. Using such a format for the accumulation step will result in strongly visible color banding artifacts. There are two approaches to solve this:

1. Use a higher bit-per-channel format for the accumulation framebuffer. You will need a separate gamma correction pass, so you need to set up render-to-texture via a FBO. `GL_RGBA16F` appears as a particularily good format for this. Since you use a PBR lighting model, you can then also work with color values outside [0,1], and instead of a simple gamma correction, apply a proper tone mapping in the final pass. Note that while you may not need an alpha chanell, still use an `RGBA` format here, the `RGB` formats are simply not required color buffer formats by the GL spec, so they may not be supported universally.
2. Store the data still in 8 bit-per-component format, gamma corrected. The key here is that the blending must still be done in linear space, so the destination framebuffer color values must be re-linearized prior to blending. This can be achieved by using a framebuffer with `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` format and enabling `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB`. In that case, the GPU will automatically apply the standard sRGB gamma correction when writing the fragment color to the framebuffer (which currently your fragment shader does), but it will also lead to the sRGB linearization when accessing to those values, including for blending. The [OpenGL 4.6 core profile spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=526) states in section "17.3.6.1 Blend equation":

   > If `FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled and the value of `FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING` for the framebuffer attachment corresponding
   >   to the destination buffer is `SRGB` (see section 9.2.3), the `R`, `G`, and `B` destination
   >   color values (after conversion from fixed-point to floating-point) are considered to
   >   be encoded for the sRGB color space and hence must be linearized prior to their
   >   use in blending. Each `R`, `G`, and `B` component is converted in the same fashion
   >   described for sRGB texture components in section 8.24.

Approach 1 will be the much more general approach, while approach 2 has a couple of drawbacks:

- the linearization/delinerization is done multiple times, potentially wasting some GPU processing power
- due to still using only 8 bit integer, the overall quality will be lower. After each blending step, the results are rounded to the next representable number, so you will get much more quantization noise.
- you are still limited to color values in [0,1] and cannot (easily) do more interesting tone mapping and HDR rendering effects

However, approach 2 also has advantages:

- you do not need a separate final gamma correction pass
- if your platform / window system does support sRGB framebuffers, you can directly create an sRGB pixeformat/visual for your window, and do not need any rende-to-texture step at all. Basically, requesting an sRGB framebuffer and enabling `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` will be enough to make this work.